# В чём смысл правок? (локальный и глобальный смыслы)

Tags: обсуждение, поиск, правки

Когда я правлю здесь сообщение, я, в первую очередь, руководствуюсь следующими факторами:

1. Повысить читаемость и структурированность
2. Исправить ошибки в именах (функции, компоненты, классы и т.п.), если я компетентен
3. Добавить метки, позволяющие проще найти соообщение
4. Каюсь, прорывается семейственность (потомственные филологи, один я не пошёл по стопам): если замечаю ошибки, опечатки, отсутствие знаков препинания - правлю. Но не буду подрываться всего лишь из-за пары ошибок.

Но, поскольку в свое время много поработал с оптимизацией информации для поисковых сервисов и до сих пор курирую кое-какие проекты, с этим связанные, а доступа к статистике у меня нет :P (это отсылка к автору чуть ранее возникшей здесь темой) возникают вопросы (применительно к SO, общие ответы я знаю, но часто бывает, что дьявол скрывается в мелочах):

1. Что важнее для поисковиков? (метки, заголовки и т.п.)
2. Есть ли пассивизация по чрезмерному количеству спец. разметки?
3. Насколько плоха статистика по ошибкам?

Ну, и главный вопрос: стоит ли вообще об этом задумываться или плюнуть и делать все "для людёв, шоб им лушше было" (С)?

Comment: Для поисковиков наиболее важен заголовок страницы (title), который составляется из первой метки + заголовка вопроса. Если рассуждать с этой точки зрения, популярные неязыковые метки типа [массивы] могут быть "вредны", так как они перебивают непопулярные языковые метки, приводя к бессмысленному заголовку (ср. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719718/Как-прочитать-данные-из-текстового-файла-и-записать-их-в-массив и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757004/как-инициализировать-5-ти-мерный-массив)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Не согласен. Влияние title переоценено, на мой взгляд, поскольку сильно зависит от сочетания других факторов. Проверено экспериментально

Comment: В смысле "переоценено"? Вопрос, на который я дал ссылку, в поисковой выдаче по запросу "pascal Как прочитать данные из текстового файла и записать их в массив" ниже вопросов, явно содержащих в заголовке слово Pascal.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight это не обязательно заслуга title. Чтобы определить весовые доли разных параметров оптимизации, нужна статистика за достаточно длинный период, и программа, её анализирующая, стоит немалых денег :)

Comment: С ошибками всё очень плохо. Я сам не образец грамотности, но категорически отказываюсь понимать, в чём сложность проверить мягкий знак в окончании тся/ться или пары предлогов в/из и на/с. А пробелы перед запятыми! Они делают меня несчастным. Полное ощущение, что Маугли вышел из джунглей, чтобы задать вопрос про PHP.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Уууу! Чтобы видеть ошибки, надо знать, что ты ошибся. Приходится работать со студентами: даже окончившие университет и весьма неплохо разбирающиеся в профильном предмете, могут написать диктант по Маршаку на двойку :(

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ваш пример доказывает обратное. Обратите внимание - все слова **кроме** Pascal в заголовке вопроса присутствуют - но это вопросу не помогло :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov "доказывает обратное" - преувеличение. Почему слова вроде "прочитать", "данные", "файл" не помогли, объяснить легко - они встречаются в интернете намного чаще, чем "pascal", и играют меньшую роль.

Answer (score 9):

> TL;DR Рекомендации поисковых машин давно уже в один голос говорят об одном и
>   том же: делайте сайты для людей.

В эпоху, когда на рынке веб-аналитики царят аффилированные с поисковиками системы и поисковики имеют широчайший доступ к поведенческим факторам — это действительно работает.

Для людей важен заголовок — это входная дверь в конкретный вопрос, его виднее всего при поиске (как по сайту, так и по внешнему). Мы обращаем внимание и на то, как аккуратно оформлен вопрос. Чтобы были абзацы, код отформатирован как код, чтобы длинные вопросы прорежались картинками или как-то ещё визуально были опрятными.

По ошибкам — для этого [в том числе и для этого] мы дубликатим вопросы, поисковики учитывают взаимные ссылки вопросов. Люди — не знаю, за всех говорить не могу, но лично я всегда смотрю на правый блок связанных вопросов.

Глобальный смысл правок — сделать вопрос лучше. Удивлены, да?

Если вопрос можно сделать лучше — делайте. Единственное, я могу сказать, что не стоит пытаться улучшить вопросы, на которых большими буквами написано, что их только в морг. Очень часто хочется поправить пару опечаток, но ты понимаешь, что вопрос из тех, что уже пора в морг — ну так лучше пройти мимо и потратить время на какой-нибудь более полезный вопрос.

Причём, я много раз сталкивался с этим моментом, когда мне указывали, что вопрос не стоит усилий — а я обижался. Мне же хотелось как лучше!

Но вопросы вопросам рознь. Одни вопросы не будут полезны никому, кроме топикстартера, другие будут полезны сотням людей многие годы спустя. Некоторые вопросы даже топикстартеру не нужны — не потрудился написать хорошо и понятно, не получил ответ, ушёл с сайта, чтобы не вернуться.

Если вы не можете найти подходящие вопросы, на которые вы сумеете ответить — это повод уйти учиться, чтобы повышать свою квалификацию. (Можно задавать свои вопросы, чтобы повысить квалификацию) Но чего точно не стоит делать — так это в муках прокрастинации исправлять пару буковок, уверяя себя, что делаете полезное дело. Вот и вроде на подобных правках набрал 2к репутации — а время всё равно что в мусорку выброшено.

А насчёт локального смысла правок... Локальный смысл правок в один топик не помещается. Возьмите любой фактор из вашего вопроса — вы найдёте не одну тему по одному конкретному вопросу. Ту же букву е/ё как минимум три топика есть. По форматированию кода — десяток. И так далее.

Comment: (убедительная просьба прекратить использовать два дефиса вместо тире, ваши тексты заставляют меня плакать)

Comment: @andreymal не на всех клавах есть нормальные тире.

Comment: @alexolut на любой компьютерной клаве можно прикрутить типографскую раскладку

Comment: @andreymal мне такое нафиг не сдалось, например. На экранной клаве, пожалуйста, но аппаратную «портить» не собираюсь.

Comment: @alexolut во-первых, добавление сочетания клавиш Alt+дефис называть порчей это какой-то бред. Во-вторых, даже если так, лучше уж использовать один дефис вместо тире, чем ставить вырвиглазные два

Comment: @andreymal ну, кто-то вообще большие буквы забанил, авторский стиль... такие дела.

Comment: В винде – Alt + 0150

Comment: У меня `&mdash;` уже в мышечной памяти %)

Comment: В винде можно создать при помощи msklc и поставить себе кастомную раскладку, в которой есть что угодно — и тире, и «правильные» кавычки.